# display side by side lists (ul) inside a drop down list

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I have been struggling with HTML and CSS and i am trying to get the list in my drop down to display side by side, inline and center? Once i have figured out the correct method i will use the div with the class names "left", "middle" and "right" on all the drop down menus.

here is a pic of what i have got to:
[image]

So like you can see in the bath dropdown in the image above i have them in 3 columns they are not inline and there is a gap either side i cannot seem to remove? eventually i will have an extra column on each dropdown which will have a image in it.

Any help would be great and as with all my questions so far a brief description of why would be awesome just so i can get a better understanding as i am learning as i go.

here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/qesmow58/5/

```css
.header-menu-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.headermenu {
  padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #17D8C7;
}

.headermenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.headermenu>ul>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.headermenu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.headermenu .arrow {
  line-height: 0%;
  font-size: 8px
}

.headermenu>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.headermenu>ul>li>div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #aa2ebf;
  background-color: white;
  width: 450px;
}

.headermenu>ul>li:hover>div {
  display: block;
}

.left,
.middle,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-menu-wrap">
  <nav class="headermenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ON SALE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Suites</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Baths<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div>
          <div class="left">
            <ul class="bathdropdown1">
              <li>
                <h3>Bath Types</h3>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Standard</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">L-Shaped</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">B-Shaped</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="middle">
            <ul class="bathdropdown2">
              <li>
                <h3>Bath Accessories</h3>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Bath Screens</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bath Panels</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <ul class="bathdropdown3">
              <li>
                <h3>All Baths</h3>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Toilets<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div>
          <ul class="toiletdropdown1">
            <li>
              <h3>Toilet Style</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Back to Wall</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Close Coupled</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Comfort Height</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fully Back to Wall</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Low Level</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Toilet and Basin Units</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="toiletdropdown2">
            <li>
              <h3>Toilet Accessories</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Concealed Cisterns</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="toiletdropdown3">
            <li>
              <h3>All Toilet Types</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Basins<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div>
          <ul class="basindropdown1">
            <li>
              <h3>Style</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Basin and Pedestal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cloakroom</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="basindropdown2">
            <li>
              <h3>All Basins</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">All Basins</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Shower Enclosures<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div>
          <ul class="showerenclosuredropdown1">
            <li>
              <h3>Amelia Enclosures
                <h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Amelia Bifold Door</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Amelia Enclosure Side Panels</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Amelia Pivot Door</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Amelia Quadrant Enclosure</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Amelia Sliding Door</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="showerenclosuredropdown2">
            <li>
              <h3>Sienna Enclosures</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sienna Quadrant</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sienna Bifold Door</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sienna Pivot Door</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sienna Sliding Door</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sienna Wet Room Screen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sienna Enclosure Side Panels</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="showerenclosuredropdown3">
            <li>
              <h3>Show Trays</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Shower Trays</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Riser Kits</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Furniture<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div>
          <ul class="furnituredropdown1">
            <li>
              <h3>Collection</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Bella Collection</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Caprice Collection</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gino Collection</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shine Collection</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sienna Collection</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Valentino Collection</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="furnituredropdown2">
            <li>
              <h3>Unit Type</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Vanity Unit and Basin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wall Vanity Unit and Basin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Corner Vanity Unit and Basin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Back to Wall Units</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cupboard Units</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mini Units</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Showers<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div>
          <ul class="showersdropdown1">
            <li>
              <h3>Style</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Round Head</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Square Head</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Taps<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div>
          <ul class="tapsdropdown1">
            <li>
              <h3>Bathroom Taps</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Mono Mixer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bath Shower Mixer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mini Mono Mixer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bath Filler</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="tapsdropdown2">
            <li>
              <h3>Kitchen Taps</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="tapsdropdown3">
            <li>
              <h3>All Taps</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Accessories<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div>
          <ul class="accessoriesdropdown1">
            <li><a href="#">Wastes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I have just had a brainwave which i will try in a minute, if i place the individual list in there own divs in the drop down, will that allow them to sit inline?? lets find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
.left, .middle, .right {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qesmow58/8/

Comment: ah wow, ok thank you. just so i understand is it the float and box-sizing that align it?? and is the 33.3% defining the space each should take up? 
Could you please elaborate on the box-sizing bit as i have yet to use/understand its uses?

Comment: The `box-sizing: border-box;` is not important at all. Box sizing counts the width or height with all the paddings/borders etc.

You can read about it here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

I've set `width: 33.3%;` because you have 3 columns and every of them should have the same width (100/3=33.3). Then I used `float: left;` so the elements are in the same line.

Comment: Also don't forget to `clear` after floating. 

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float_images_side

In this example you can see something similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

- Give the `div` a class which you have used to wrap drop-down items so that you can be specific for that particular `div`. Here i have given `sub-menu-container` class to it
- Add `vertical-align: top` to `.left, .middle, .right`. this is
  because you have set `display: inline-block` to them.

```css
.header-menu-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.headermenu {
  padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #17D8C7;
}

.headermenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.headermenu > ul > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.headermenu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.headermenu .arrow {
  line-height: 0%;
  font-size: 8px
}

.headermenu > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.headermenu > ul > li > div.sub-menu-container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #aa2ebf;
  background-color: white;
  width: 450px;
}

.headermenu > ul > li:hover > div {
  display: block;
}


.left, .middle, .right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-menu-wrap">
   <nav class="headermenu">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">ON SALE</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Suites</a></li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Baths<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <div class="sub-menu-container">
               <div class="left">
                  <ul class="bathdropdown1">
                     <li>
                        <h3>Bath Types</h3>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#">Standard</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">L-Shaped</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">B-Shaped</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="middle">
                  <ul class="bathdropdown2">
                     <li>
                        <h3>Bath Accessories</h3>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#">Bath Screens</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Bath Panels</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="right">
                  <ul class="bathdropdown3">
                     <li>
                        <h3>All Baths</h3>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Toilets<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <div class="sub-menu-container">
               <ul class="toiletdropdown1">
                  <li>
                     <h3>Toilet Style</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Back to Wall</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Close Coupled</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Comfort Height</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fully Back to Wall</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Low Level</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Toilet and Basin Units</a></li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="toiletdropdown2">
                  <li>
                     <h3>Toilet Accessories</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Concealed Cisterns</a></li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="toiletdropdown3">
                  <li>
                     <h3>All Toilet Types</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Basins<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <div class="sub-menu-container">
               <ul class="basindropdown1">
                  <li>
                     <h3>Style</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Basin and Pedestal</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Cloakroom</a></li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="basindropdown2">
                  <li>
                     <h3>All Basins</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">All Basins</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Shower Enclosures<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <div class="sub-menu-container">
               <ul class="showerenclosuredropdown1">
                  <li>
                     <h3>Amelia Enclosures</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Amelia Bifold Door</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Amelia Enclosure Side Panels</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Amelia Pivot Door</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Amelia Quadrant Enclosure</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Amelia Sliding Door</a></li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="showerenclosuredropdown2">
                  <li>
                     <h3>Sienna Enclosures</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sienna Quadrant</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sienna Bifold Door</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sienna Pivot Door</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sienna Sliding Door</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sienna Wet Room Screen</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sienna Enclosure Side Panels</a></li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="showerenclosuredropdown3">
                  <li>
                     <h3>Show Trays</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Shower Trays</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Riser Kits</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Furniture<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <div class="sub-menu-container">
               <ul class="furnituredropdown1">
                  <li>
                     <h3>Collection</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Bella Collection</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Caprice Collection</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Gino Collection</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Shine Collection</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sienna Collection</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Valentino Collection</a></li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="furnituredropdown2">
                  <li>
                     <h3>Unit Type</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Vanity Unit and Basin</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Wall Vanity Unit and Basin</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Corner Vanity Unit and Basin</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Back to Wall Units</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Cupboard Units</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mini Units</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Showers<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <div class="sub-menu-container">
               <ul class="showersdropdown1">
                  <li>
                     <h3>Style</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Round Head</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Square Head</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Taps<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <div class="sub-menu-container">
               <ul class="tapsdropdown1">
                  <li>
                     <h3>Bathroom Taps</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mono Mixer</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Bath Shower Mixer</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mini Mono Mixer</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Bath Filler</a></li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="tapsdropdown2">
                  <li>
                     <h3>Kitchen Taps</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="tapsdropdown3">
                  <li>
                     <h3>All Taps</h3>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Accessories<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <div class="sub-menu-container">
               <ul class="accessoriesdropdown1">
                  <li><a href="#">Wastes</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qesmow58/13/)